# Import wav files to iPhone using SD card reader

Tags: ios, file-transfer, sd-card, audio

I have the below SD card reader that imports photos and videos to iOS photos app. Is it possible to import .wav files onto my iPhone using the Apple lightning port SD card reader?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, you can only transfer certain images and videos.  This adapter will not transfer documents or audio files.

You could put those audio files on Dropbox or a network drive and then access them with the iPhone.  You should be able to transfer the wav's that way.