# Solution for moving WAV raw audio files from SD cards directly to IOS devices?

Tags: ios, audio, sd-card

I have WAV (raw audio) files on an SD card, recorded with a Zoom H4N digital recorder. In the field, I need a way to get the WAV files off of the card.

Here's what doesn't work: Apple's card reader only does images and video. I have one, I've tried it. (
[Import wav files to iPhone using SD card reader](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/242908/import-wav-files-to-iphone-using-sd-card-reader) )

I do not want to lug an entire Mac along, just to plug in an SD card and copy some data. (If I have a Mac, I can just plug the digital recorder in and copy data off.)

I'm looking at SD cards with in-built wifi -- eg Ascend's which has a companion IOS app. But these all seem to presume the SD card is in a camera of some sort.

Do I need to add software or hardware to solve this problem?

Comment: @IconDaemon the iExplorer you linked is not an IOS app (as far as I can see on their web page) ... how does that apply to my question? ...or what am I misunderstanding re your comment??

Comment: Sorry. Misread your question.

Comment: ...rats! I was hoping I’d missed something :)

Comment: You may just have to lug the Mac around. :-(